# Learning to read and write recursively

Tags: recursion, clojure

I am very new to Clojure and I've seen this pattern in other languages before. I think I do know how recursion works, yet I don't know how to read and how to think the way, that allows you to write code like that. Here's a trivial example:

```
(defn remove-dups [str]
  (when-let [[fst & rst] (seq str)]
    (if (= fst (first rst))
      (remove-dups rst)
      (cons fst (remove-dups rst)))))
```

I'm sure to an experienced Clojurist this doesn't look very difficult. However, I still don't know how to read code like this. Maybe there's a pattern you have to learn to understand? They say Lisp and Clojure reads "from inside-out", yet I can't find a quick way to mentally parse code like this. Maybe there's a way to "unwrap" recursive patterns by printing out steps? Please someone teach me to think in divide-and-conquer terms.

Comment: Aside: This isn't good code, inasmuch as it consumes stack and so will crash if too many recursion steps are needed. If `loop` / `recur` and `trampoline` can't be used (and loop/recur *can't* be used here, because it's not in tail position), a different construct, ie. `for`, is appropriate.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I hear ya. Sorry I couldn't find a better example. If I could write better Clojure code I wouldn't be asking this question in the first place. I think though this code perfectly illustrates my struggle and the struggle is real ;[

Comment: I hear you; unfortunately, I don't have any good advice. My own approach consisted of an extended period of repeated exposure until things clicked, but that doesn't mean I know how to make that process easier for anyone else. Though, yes, one *can* "unwrap" things, but while I could teach that with a whiteboard, it's not as easy with text. Maybe talking over the process for converting between iterative and recursive algorithms would work, but the easy algorithm for that only works in the same scenarios where TCO does, and this example isn't one of 'em.

Comment: Give [this](http://www.braveclojure.com/functional-programming/#Recursion_Instead_of_for_while) a read.  Better examples will help.

Comment: Another aside: often you can combine library functions instead of directly `cons`ing together lists recursively. This example becomes `(->> str (partition-by identity) (map first))`.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect this is a question many people who want to approach Clojure are asking themselves and most are afraid to ask, so thanks for reaching out. It's also a very personal undertaking to wrap your brain around recursion. And I say that from expierence. Back in College I was a teaching assistant for the course that introduced recursion (for five years) and I spend those five years trying to figure out "the way" to "show" people how to unwrap code snippets like this.

Over that time I developed these ideas that seemed to hold in every case:

- Nobody could read this code on first exposure
- Once they "got it" they could not then explain it in a useful way to those who did not yet "get it".
- the time required to "get it" was completely *RANDOM* and in no way correlated with success in other areas of the course (unless they dropped the class)

So my conclusion was that **learning to read this code changes your brain** somehow, and that change takes a random amount of time. Everyone goes about learning it differently, and everyone ends up in the same place.

here are some of the approaches I took for different people:

- watch it with a debugger (for hours if required): in Clojure this would be setting up Leiningen+emacs+clj-refactor and adding a trace to the function. then running it and stepping through it repeatedly.
- draw the stack on paper (start at the bottom of the page) and run many examples *all the way through*. People who stepped all the way through even after they claimed to understand it did better.
- some people really did learn this by staring intently at the code for hours. As an educator i have no idea how to help with this other than not interrupting them (teachers often interrupt learning)
- some people walked out of the class, went drinking, and came back with understanding. again, no idea what they did, though i suspect they had more fun than the other groups.

Be patient, learning to really read this example will improve every aspect of your life as a programmer, and in my personal opinion this example is completely fine and well suited to this purpose.

Comment: Working through [The Little Schemer](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/little-schemer), one step at a time, is what changed my brain.  Nothing else that I'd tried worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think exposure to [Mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) can help a lot with understanding recursion. Once you're comfortable with such proofs on numbers, try reading some based on trees/graphs. Mathematical induction usually goes from n to n+1. Recursion usually goes the other way - you have a problem of size n, you reduce it to a problem of size n-1. Eventually you end-up with a problem of size 1 or 0 which is usually trivial to solve.

The divide-an-conquer strategy usually used for sequences is dividing them into a head (the first item) and a (possibly empty) tail (the rest of the items). This is done in the code example above with the line `[fst & rst] (seq str)`. This uses a Clojure feature called destructuring. It's equivalent to the following

`(let [fst (first str)
       rst (rest str)])`

This is a common idiom in most recursive functions dealing with sequences. Once you've divided the sequence, you usually want to somehow unite it back together (perhaps changing some elements, dropping some, etc). The way you do this is you **cons**truct a sequence one element at a time using `cons`.

Now to the specifics of `remove-duplicates`: if the head of the sequence is equal to the first element of the tail, then we have two consecutive elements which are equal and the semantics of the function require us to drop one of them. We drop the first one (the tail) and proceed processing the rest of the sequence, by making a recursive call `(remove-dups rst)`. If they are not the same, then we need to keep the head in the result, so we cons it to `(remove-dups rst)` (which will be computed in the next step of the recursion).

The simplified version is below.

`(defn remove-dups [str]
  (if (empty? str)
    nil
    (let [fst (first str)
          rst (rest str)]
      (if (= fst (first rst))
        (remove-dups rst)
        (cons fst (remove-dups rst))))))`

One way to improve this further would be to return an empty string "" instead of nil on line 3.